# В чем принципиальная разница RoR и Python (Django)?

Tags: python, ruby, сравнение

После работы на чистом "Си" решил для себя идти в дотНет направлении, но никак не получается, не выходит. Два дня назад было 9-тое собеседование в котором я понял что просто не тяну. Реально дотНет очень большой, всегда найдется момент о котором ты не знаешь на котором тебя обязательно поймают, после чистого «Си» этот C# имеет очень много всяких «финтифлюшек» в которых просто теряешься, не в обиду дотНетчикам но всякого мусора в C# просто навалом. Конечно я когда прошел кучу собеседований я познал много всяких тонкостей о которых не знал но всё равно, слишком много всего ! Я не знаю как там в Java но дотНет очень большая платформа, для меня это сложно, видать не тот мозг ! Уйду в Ruby или Python, хотя говорят что это для тех кто «неасилил» C#\Java наверно оно так и есть ! Последний надеюсь мой вопрос к вам коллеги : если строить web-приложение принципиальная разница есть между RoR или Python(Django) как по мне всё очень похоже! Спасибо всем, счастья, добра, удачи...

Comment: >но всякого мусора в C# просто навалом

например?

Comment: Как надоели уже подобные вопросы..

Comment: Для меня было большим разочарованием отсутствие аналога rails generate в Diango и Django-admin в Rails. А вообще принципиальной разницы для меня тоже нет, ну разве что только Django кажется более прозрачным чем Rails, а Rails более для ленивых, хотя каждому свое, попробуйте оба фреймворка, лучше чем вы сами никто не сможет ответить на ваш вопрос.

Comment: @Niki-Timofe Хороший ответ ! Спасибо ...

Comment: мозг не тянет, не осилю, слишком много фич и т.п. Как после освоенного вами языка си такие мысли приходят к вам в голову? У программистов таких мыслей вообще возникать не должно. Или освой необходимую технологию или умри стараясь (хотя до второго не доходит никогда).

Comment: а, может, вам лучше просто по сишным собеседованиям пройтись? :)

Comment: И Ruby и Python - тоже очень объёмные платформы с огромным количеством библиотек и тонкостей. Сколько ни учи, всё равно чего-то да знать не будешь. Так что направление уж выбирайте сами. На рынке всему применение найдётся. Особенно хорошему Cшнику.

Answer (score 4):

Важная ремарка. Данный ответ **не является** ответом на вопрос. Это еще один комментарий к ответу пользователя [@Jarto](/users/11499/jarto). Пишу как ответ в силу того, что возможность комментировать вопрос пропала. Поэтому, если есть возможность, прошу перенести его в комментарии.

> а чего такого в Ubuntu домохозяйкам не хватает-то?

[@pirj](/users/8513/pirj) начнем с того, что операционные системы используются не только домохозяйками. Это было лишь некоторое обобщение. Очень широкий сектор их использования - корпоративный. А потому помимо обычных пользователей (домохозяек, домохозяинов, студентов, пенсионеров и всех-все-всех) есть еще всяческие служащие, менеджеры, бухгалтеры, для которых компьютер является рабочим инструментом (не буду относить сюдя айтишников - среди них распространение линукса довольно велико, но они в отличие от служащих и просто пользователей не исчисляются сотнями миллионов)

Так вот. Почему же не Linux:

1. MS Office. Да, я знаю, что есть Open Office, Libre Office и что-нибудь еще. Но главенствующую роль все же занимает именно продукт Microsoft, а все остальные, хорошо это или плохо, вынуждены под  него подстраиваться. Даже если вы внутри своей компании полностью откажетесь от использования MS Office, заставить другие компании сделать то же самое вы не сможете. А уж обмен всяческой документацией между теми или иными компаниями, фирмами, ведомствами - дело самое обычное. Не будете же вы требоватьот какого-нибудь банка/налоговой/службы безопасности присылать вам документы в формате odt.
2. Привычка. Отучить десятки миллионов пользователей от Windows и приучить к Linux - задача непростая. Даже если ваша супруга с ней может справиться, не факт, что с ней справятся сотни (или хотя бы десятки) миллионов других людей. Да, Ubuntu смогла повернуться лицом к пользователю, и не выглядит как эротическая мечта красноглазого линуксоида, но дьявол, как известно, кроется в деталях.  А смириться с этими деталями многим непросто.
3. Игры (не самая важная, но довльно значимая причина). Что бы там ни говорили про портирование Доты и всяческие похвальные начинания от Valve, Linux даже близко не является игровой осью. На нем нет ни одного классного и коммерчески успешного эксклюзива (если даже я ошибаюсь, то их единицы), те хорошие игры, что есть, являются в основном портами, и портируются в лучшем случае ненамного позднее их выхода на Win. И это при том, что Windows сама по себе не очень может похвастаться изобилием. Я уже не говорю про довольно хреновую ситуацию с драйверами видеокарт - насколько мне известно, производительность одних и тех же моделей видеокарт отличаются в худшую сторону на Linux по сравнению с их аналогами, работающими из-под Windows. Я уже не говорю, что всяческие конфигурации, когда на ноутбуке стоят встроенная и дискретная видеокарты, заставляют пользователя плясать с бубном, чтобы заставить  работать дискретную карту.
4. На большинство компьютеров при покупке уже предустановлена Windows. Является ли это происками злыдней из компании Макрософак, или карой Всевышнего за наши земные грехи, но это факт.
5. Практически полное отсутствие рекламы. А она, как известно, двигатель торговли. Если спросить у не-айтишников, почему бы им не поставить Linux, подавляющее большинство из них ответит "А что это?"
6. И наконец, самая главная причина. **ЗАЧЕМ?** Что такого сулит простому пользователю Linux, ради чего он сломя голову бросится его устанавливать?  Как известно, от добра добра не ищут (даже если это "добро" - Windows). Пользователь в основной своей массе ленив, и ему это просто не нужно.

Answer (score 2):

стоял когда-то перед таким выбором )

По поводу C#, язык хороший, но мне кажется сильно много чувства исключительности у людей, которые его продвигают.

То что касается Python и Ruby, советую их учить оба, но для веб разработки выбрать Rails. У  Django возможно больше серьезных проектов, но скажу с большой уверенностью, что Rails развиваются быстрее, это видно из частоты выхода релизов как самого Rails так и Ruby.
Также не смотря на то что эти языки похожи как братья у них есть отличия, и основное отличие в концепции разработки на этих языках:

```
Python - среди множества решений проблемы только одно правильное
Ruby   - у одной проблемы есть множество решений(нет предела совершенству)
```

пока конечно Ruby не хватает проворности для высоконагруженных проектов, которая например есть в Java, но все настолько быстро изменяется и растет.

Единственное для изучения механизмов Web-разработки Ruby не рекомендуют для новичков в этом деле, потому что вам изначально нужно непосредственно разобраться в Web технологиях, и тут Ruby может показаться сложноватым, рекомендую начать не с Rails для освоения, а скажем со статических страниц jekyll, создайте для начала себе блог на Octopress и разберитесь в нем, а потом переходите уже к изучению самих Rails

... и еще )), кто программирует на Ruby, делает это только на Mac или Linux, забудьте про Win, для Ruby этой системы практически не существует

Comment: >По поводу C#, язык хороший, но мне кажется сильно много чувства исключительности у людей, которые его продвигают

тема сисек....в смысле, исключительности не раскрыта

Comment: C# закрытое сообщество, Ruby открытое сообщество, я не знаю может это opensource, может еще что-то, но даже Python в этом вопросе мне кажется немного проигрывает, возможно это отпечаток Google ))

Comment: а в чем тут недостаток/достоинство?

Comment: все больше и больше становится разработчиков Ruby и все меньше разработчиков C#

Comment: можете подтвердить это чем-то? Насчет "больше разработчиков Ruby" охотно поверю. Но вот "все меньше разработчиков C#" - это адская чушь

Comment: ну что вы от меня хотите, ну не пишут люди на C# под Linux, нет нормального рантайма, кто хочет тот сидит в Windows песочнице на Шарпе. Есть куча примеров перехода Window-Linux и практически нет Linux-Windows. Уже даже Доту партировали, скоро забирут от вас последний ваш оплот, компьютерные игры и будете вообще лапу сосать. Если говорить о Web, то все сервера работают на Nix, за исключением экзотических извращенцев типо ООН, которые свою систему на Win деплоят

Comment: @Jarto, радует Ваш взгляд на M$, но при чем здесь Ruby?

Вот [обширный обзор](http://www.ohloh.net/languages/compare?measure=commits&percent=true&l0=java&l1=csharp&l2=objective_c&l3=visualbasic&l4=perl&l5=c&l6=cpp&l7=php&l8=python&l9=javascript&l10=-1&commit=Update) opensource проектов. 

Полазив по сайту, можно выбрать весьма разнообразную инфу.

Comment: @DreamChild, настораживает, что в обеих Ваших ссылках не указано *к каким единицам измерения* относятся приведенные там проценты.

Подозреваю, что это сумма продаж. 

Тогда, естественно, что доля *бесплатной* ОС будет равна нулю.

Comment: @avp нет, это не число продаж (в частности, WinXP давно не продается и даже если бы продавался, его продажи точно не составляли бы сейчас более сорока процентов от общего числа). Это статистика по числу пользователей этих операционных систем. Не берусь утверждать, как она собирается, но смею вас уверить, что эти конторы предоставляют более чем точные данные. Вот кстати [еще немного][1] статистики. Тут она чуть более радужна для Linux, однако даже тут его доля ненамного выше статистической погрешности при всем уважении к это оси

[1]:http://www.w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_os.asp

Comment: @avp, @DreamChild хохмы ради (2005г, П.Грэм):

     A recent survey found 52% of companies are replacing Windows servers with Linux servers. 

     More significant, I think, is which 52% they are. At this point, anyone proposing to run Windows on servers should be prepared to explain what they know about servers that Google, Yahoo, and Amazon don't.

Comment: @DreamChild, опять про ссылки

    Note: W3Schools is a website for people with an interest for web technologies.

Т.е. в Вашем комментарии статистика ОС с которых заходили на  сервера W3Schools 

(а я, вообще, до сих пор о такой и не слышал)

 люди, интересующиеся web-технологиями.

--

Ну, как говорится, есть ложь, есть большая ложь и есть *статистика*.

Собственно, они сами пишут: Statistics Can Be Misleading.

Comment: @avp давайте все же будем логичны - я привел три источника, в каждом из которых указываются примерно схожие цифры. Даже если учитывать, что контора W3Schools далеко не Google, другие данные лишь подтверждают их цифры. У меня нет ни малейшего желания очернить славный Linux, однако факты говорят сами за себя. Кстати [вот][1] свежий опрос с Хабра. Как видите, даже на таком ресурсе доля Linux - всего около 22%. А там сами понимаете какая аудитория - далеко не домохозяйки. Домохозяйкам Linux не нужен вовсе. А их среди пользователей как раз большинство

[1]:http://habrahabr.ru/post/190414/

Comment: @DreamChild ну google дал такие ссылки (на педивикию): http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_operating_systems и http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linux_adoption . А что касается домохозяек -- так им всё равно -- win/linux/McOS/чёрт лысый. Но. Вспомнился репортаж на Euronews прошлого десятилетия, что в Эстермадуре органы госуправления и интернет-кафе переведены на linux. Экономия -- миллионов 20 (хотя за цифру не ручаюсь -- давно это было)

Comment: @DreamChild, ну ничего себе, **всего лишь 22 %**. 

Я и не думал, что хоть у какой-то достаточно большой группы этот процент будет больше 10, 15%.

А насчет десктопов (ноутов) у домохозяек по всему миру - думаю Вы правы, но стоит ли для них писать *новые* программы?

Мне кажется, в ближайшие 5-10 лет ситуация здесь сильно изменится в сторону *настоящих* облаков с реально распределенными приложениями. А дома (на рабочих местах) останутся по сути терминалы и периферия разного вида.

Comment: @avp на Хабре этот показатель вообще по идее должен быть не менее 50% - все-таки там сидят почти сплошь айтишники, знакомые с Linux не понаслышке. А вот основная масса пользователей (подавляющее большинство даже) сидит под Windows и никуда из под него не уйдет в сколько-нибудь обозримой перспективе - им это абсолютно незачем.

Comment: @alexlz домохозяйкам не всё равно - они просто не перейдут на Linux, им это незачем. А что касается экспериментов по переводу учреждений - их было немало, в том числе и удачных, но они погоды почти не делают. Факторов, ограничивающих распространение Linux среди обычных, не-айтишеных пользователей тьма-тьмущая, и чтобы их преодолеть, необходимы огромные усилия, которые приложить просто некому.

Comment: @DreamChild maybe, maybe

      домохозяйкам не всё равно - они просто не перейдут на Linux, им это незачем.

тут есть один момент. Откуда они не перейдут на linux? В США в прошлом был удачный маркетинговый ход одной фруктовой фирмы по насыщению образовательных учреждений своей яблочной продукцией по заниженным ценам. Выпускники этих учреждений вроде впоследствии выбирали их продукцию уже по нормальным ценам. 

Я не в курсе, как идёт внедрение линуха в школы, но думаю, что идёт. И нафига домохозяйкам, тыкавшим в школе кнопки под линухом, нужны винды. Так что, поживём-посмотрим.

Comment: @alexlz остается только подождать этих удачных маркетинговых ходов. Только вот от кого? Я не исключаю уменьшение доли Windows, но скорее всего это случится не за счет Linux - ему уже пара десятков лет, но он даже не подобрался к пяти процентам. У него слишком много проблем (в том числе и не его собственных), из-за которых такой переход видится очень маловероятным

Comment: @DreamChild

>Я не исключаю уменьшение доли Windows, но скорее всего это случится не за счет Linux

А за счет кого?

Comment: @DreamChild ну Ванга из меня не получится, так что на правильность прогнозов претендовать не буду. Но http://www.spohelp.ru/software/categories/5-operatsionnye-sistemy/titles . А, учитывая, что разговор идёт о домохозяйках (т.е. вариант win8/linux на виртуалке не катит), осмелюсь предсказать рост количества линухов на домашних компутерах по мере увеличения количества школьников, которых будут линуксами мучить в школах. Дабы ребёнку было проще учиться...

Comment: @alexlz хорошо, если линухами. А не БолгенОСами какими-нибудь))

Comment: тут вопрос не Linux или Window, тут вопрос opensource - не opensource. Win эту войну проиграл.

@avp
{радует Ваш взгляд на M$, но при чем здесь Ruby?}
Ruby c Win не дружит и обслуживает эту систему по остаточному принципу

и вообще Win и opensource вещи пока не совместимые



@Jarto, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку {} редактора.

Comment: >тут вопрос не Linux или Window, тут вопрос opensource - не opensource

Во-первых, в качестве "убийственных" аргументов вы высказываете портирование Доты и ряда других игр. Какое отношение это имеет к opensource? 

Во-вторых, вы реально считаете, что наличие opensource-проектов является решающим фактором в развитии языка? Важным - возможно, но решающим - маловероятно

Comment: @mikillskegg во-первых, за счет мобильных осей (именно за их счет уже был "закрыт" "баг № 1" в Ubuntu. Хотя, если речь идет именно о десктопах, то они не в счет) 

во-вторых, за счет MacOS - ее хотя бы есть кому продвигать, что вполне неплохо получается

Comment: @DreamChild, макось пока жестко привязан к эппловскому железу. И после сметри Джобса будущее этой компании весьма туманно. К тому же, они и так занимают свою достаточно твердую нишу. Вот если они сделают версию своей оси для обычных PC, вот это будет интересно. Но я пока о таких планах не слышал (может, и ошибаюсь). Да и вообще это закрытое ПО.

Мобильные оси - они и есть мобильные оси, у нас разговор за десктопы.

Так что пока более-менее реальную альтернативу виндам кроме линукса я не вижу. Если только бсдешники не станут двигать свои системы в массы.

Comment: @mikillskegg, не факт, что таковые альтернативы появятся вообще. В ближайшие годы уж точно. Они не появятся на пустом месте. Я уже не раз говорил выше - для того, чтобы Linux стал таковой альтернативой, ему нужно преодолеть ряд проблем. За счет чего? Я не вижу. Не спорю, Шаттлворт со своей компанией проделал немалый объем работы, Ubuntu видится удобной системой даже для простого юзера, но рынок операционных систем же давно таков, что одиночки (даже состоятельные) его изменить не в силах. Опять же скажу, пока нет того, кто смог бы приложить необходимые усилия для вывода Linux на новый уровень

Comment: @DreamChild, а чего такого в Ubuntu домохозяйкам не хватает-то? Что за новый уровень? Тут супруга переходила с Win7 на Win8, вся опплевалась, и мне кажется, что переход на Ubuntu ей бы дался ровно так же. Только было бы гораздо меньше проблем у меня с настройкой этой _хрени_, в которой периодически элементы управления от 3.11 остались.

Answer (score 0):

Мой опыт:
1. Сначала PHP. Опыт 10 лет. Было очень интересно. Сделал много проектов.
2. Затем 2 года на Ruby on Rails. Было трудно, и эта трудность не спадала.
3. Затем 0,5 года на Django. Очень понравилось. Всем советую. Django однозначно проще Rails - порог вхождения точно ниже. Есть готовая админка. Работает очень быстро при правильном программировании. Если не попрет Django, то в Rails будет еще сложнее.
4. Выбираю преимущественно Ruby on Rails! Ruby on Rails - технологичнее и инновационнее, это неоспоримо. Еще плюс для меня, у меня опыта в нем больше.